# Security vulnerability or not?

Tags: security

I observed that the web tool project I'm working on has a potential vulnerability, where a well-forged http form request can make the internal server execute arbitrary shell command.

However, the web tool page is only accessible to my company's internal network and users. Although the attacker can still make a malicious page which forges the request and trap our internal user into clicking on the malicious page, it seems to be difficult for attacker to figure out a well-forged http request without direct access to the webpage. In such case, is that still a serious vulnerability which needs to be solved?

Sorry I'm not very familiar with security. Please let me know if further information is needed.

Comment: Well, this isn't a good forum for this type of question, maybe ask on http://security.stackexchange.com... also is it your responsibility to edit and modify the code that has the vulnerability... if so I would probably just fix it and move on... 99% of vulnerability mitigation is just finding the issue in the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually a judgement call and handled by company policy.

**If** your company is small, the entire staff can be trusted and it is certain that the application will never be used in a public setting, you may choose not to address this issue if it is hard to fix.

**If any of these is not the case**, then you should fix the vulnerability. Often times a formerly internal application becomes public and vulnerabilities are forgotten. Also, consider that an insider may be laid off and use this vulnerability for revenge.

It is always safer to fix the vulnerability. Make the tradeoff wisely.